# How to convert a String with decimals to BigDecimal and keep the decimals, in Talend Java?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, talend, bigdecimal

I'm creating a Job in Talend to transform data from a .csv file using some data from a database and then incorporate into another .csv file. During the transformation some calculation is needed to be performed on the values:

> value1 / value2 * value3

Value1 is taken from the .csv file and is by default a String representing an amount, f.e.

> "15.25"

Values 2 and 3 are taken from database and are BigDecimals with 4 decimal places.
The result of the calculation must be rounded up to 2 decimal places.

**My question is:
How to convert data from .csv file so that it could be calculated with BigDecimals from database?**

If I convert any datatype to BigDecimal it loses the decimals, f.e from String:
    BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("15.25")
The result would always be

> 15

I'v tried to do it with math context ROUND_UNNECESSARY and setScale also, but this seems not be relevant in this cases.

Comment: Using ``new BigDecimal("15.25")`` will *not* lose any data. When printing the value, it will still be ``15.25``. How do you print that BigDecimal?

Comment: Exactly, BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("15.25") prints out, 15.25    You are doing sth wrong...

Comment: As the result is exported to a .csv file, I'm checking the result of conversion in an output .csv file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BigDecimal

```
BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal("15.25");
BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal("5.25");
BigDecimal v3 = new BigDecimal("1.15");

BigDecimal v123 = v1.divide(v2, MathContext.DECIMAL64).multiply(v3);

System.out.println(v123);
System.out.println(v123.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

prints

```
3.34047619047619075
3.34
```

To perform this calculation using `double`

```
double v1 = 15.25;
double v2 = 5.25;
double v3 = 1.15;
double v123 = v1 / v2 * v3;
System.out.println(v123);
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", v123);
```

prints

```
3.34047619047619
3.34
```

If MathContext.DECIMAL128 had been used, the unrounded value would be

```
3.340476190476190476190476190476191
```

and *in this example*, both solutions are more than accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, I've found the solution:
My error while trying to perform above was that I've exported the

new BigDecimal("15.25")

to a .csv file and afterwards put this field into the calculation. Apparently Talend is converting a correctly converted BigDecimal to "15" unless I use a .toString(). So after converting the exemplary "15.25" to BigDecimal and not putting it into .csv file, below formula did the trick

```
(((v1).multiply(v2)).divide(v3, 2, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).toString()
```

Thank you @peter-lawrey